# The term '-replace' is not recognized in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am getting the "The term '-replace' is not recognized" issue while using the below code to exclude any extra quotes in the middle of the string field. Please correct me, If I am doing something wrong here?
Or Any better code suggestions to remove the extra Quotes in the middle of the string field.

Error Details: Final Status: The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Here is some sample data:

LocationID,LocationNM,DescriptionTXT,ManagingOrganizationID
"1",""PCP:Primary Care 1","Primary Care 1","355"
"2","Orthopedic Surgery and Specialty Hospital","Orthopedic Surgery and Specialty Hospital","355"
"5","Primary Care-0","Primary Care-0 C3,"VITAMIN D","355"

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
$FilePath = c:\Test

Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
 (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) | Foreach-Object {
   $_    -replace '0"x', '0x' `
        -replace '"PCP:', 'PCP:' `
        -replace ',"VITAMIN b12', ',VITAMIN b12' `
        -replace 'C3,"VITAMIN D,', 'C3,VITAMIN D,' `
        -replace 'to "spice use', 'to spice use' `
        -replace '30"x', '30x' `        
        -replace '" ', ' '  
  } | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Spaces after the continuation mark:  `-replace '30"x', '30x' \`        `

Comment: js2010 is correct: in order for `\`` to be effective as a line-continuation character, it must be _at the vey end of the line_ - not even whitespace is allowed to come after it. The linked duplicate details the rules.